# Java ArrayList Equals - Não permitir duplicidade de elementos no ArrayList

Tags: java

Boa noite pessoal!

Eu estou com dúvida em comparar os elementos duplicados no `ArrayList` criado, no caso do meu código eu gostaria que se já foi realizado o empréstimo para uma pessoa (no caso Alex) não seja possível efetuar um novo empréstimo para o Alex, mas sempre está permitindo realizar mais que um empréstimo para mesma pessoa, conseguem me ajudar por gentileza?

Eu estou utilizando o `equals`, mas se tiverem alguma outra forma de resolver sem problemas.

Desde já, obrigado!

## Como meu código estava originalmente

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Emprestimo> arrayemp1 = new ArrayList();

    System.out.println("\n== EMPRESTIMO ==");
    arrayemp1.add(new Emprestimo("SUPER HOMEM", "2/2/2020", "2/2/2020", "Alex", "Gaspar"));
    arrayemp1.add(new Emprestimo("SUPER HOMEM", "2/2/2020", "2/2/2020", "Alex", "Gaspar"));

    Emprestimo emprestimo = new Emprestimo();

    emprestimo.addEmprestimo(arrayemp1.get(0));
    emprestimo.addEmprestimo(arrayemp1.get(1));
}
```

```
public class Emprestimo {


     private ArrayList<Emprestimo> emprestimo = new ArrayList();

     public void addEmprestimo(Emprestimo emp1){ 

        if(emprestimo.equals(emp1)){
             System.out.println("Não é possível realizar mais que um empréstimo.");
        }else{
            emprestimo.add(emp1);
            System.out.println("Emprestimo realizado com sucesso.");
        }

    }

        public void imprimirEmprestimo(){
        for (int i=0; i<emprestimo.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(emprestimo.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

## Como meu código está agora

```
public class ControlaRevista {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ListaEmprestimo lista = new ListaEmprestimo();

    System.out.println("\n== EMPRESTIMO ==");

    lista.addEmprestimo(new Emprestimo("SUPER HOMEM", "2/2/2020", "2/2/2020", "Alex", "Gaspar"));
    lista.addEmprestimo(new Emprestimo("SUPER HOMEM", "2/2/2020", "2/2/2020", "Alex", "Gaspar"));

    lista.imprimirEmprestimos();
    }
}
```

```
public final class Emprestimo {
    private final Amigo amigo = new Amigo();
    private final Colecao colecao = new Colecao();   

    private final String nome;
    private final String dataEmprestimo, dataDevolucao;
    private final String nomeAmigo;
    private final String nomeLocal;

    public Emprestimo(String nome, String dataEmprestimo, String dataDevolucao, String nomeAmigo, String nomeLocal) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.dataEmprestimo = dataEmprestimo;
        this.dataDevolucao = dataDevolucao;
        this.nomeAmigo = nomeAmigo;
        this.nomeLocal = nomeLocal;
    }

   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Emprestimo{" + "Amigo=" + amigo.nomeAmigo + ", "+ colecao + ", dataEmprestimo=" + dataEmprestimo + ", dataDevolucao=" + dataDevolucao +'}';
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(nome,dataEmprestimo,dataDevolucao,nomeAmigo,amigo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Emprestimo)) return false;
        Emprestimo outro = (Emprestimo) obj;
        return Objects.equals(nome, outro.nome)
                && Objects.equals(dataEmprestimo, outro.dataEmprestimo)
                && Objects.equals(dataDevolucao, outro.dataDevolucao)
                && Objects.equals(nomeAmigo, outro.nomeAmigo)
                && Objects.equals(amigo, outro.amigo);
    }
}
```

```
public class ListaEmprestimo {

private Collection<Emprestimo> emprestimos = new LinkedHashSet<>();

public ListaEmprestimo(){
}

public void addEmprestimo(Emprestimo emp1){
        if (emprestimos.add(emp1)) {
             System.out.println("Não é possível realizar mais que um empréstimo.");
        } else {
             System.out.println("Empréstimo realizado com sucesso.");
        }
    }

    public void imprimirEmprestimos() {
        for (Emprestimo e : emprestimos) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Amigo{
    public String nomeAmigo,telefone,localAmigo;

    public Amigo(){
    }

    public Amigo(String nomeAmigo, String telefone, String localAmigo) {
        this.nomeAmigo = nomeAmigo;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.localAmigo = localAmigo;
    }

    private ArrayList<Amigo> amigo = new ArrayList();

    public void addAmigo(Amigo amigo1){  
           amigo.add(amigo1);
    }

    public void imprimirAmigo(){
        for (int i=0; i<amigo.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(amigo.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void validarEmprestimo(){
      //  if(amigo.get(1) ){
            System.out.println("Não é possível realizar mais que um empréstimo");
        //}
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Amigo{" + "nomeAmigo=" + nomeAmigo + ", telefone=" + telefone + ", localAmigo=" + localAmigo + '}';
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nomeAmigo;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public String getLocalAmigo() {
        return localAmigo;
    }  
}
```

```
public class Colecao{
    public String nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Colecao{" + "nome=" + nome + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: O que há nas classes `Amigo` e `Colecao`?

Comment: Acabei de atualizar o post. Obrigado pelo retorno Victor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, vemos isso:

```
public class Emprestimo {
     private ArrayList<Emprestimo> emprestimo = new ArrayList();

     // ... Mais código aqui ...
}
```

Isso não tem sentido. Significa que um `Emprestimo` tem uma lista de `Emprestimo`s. O que acontece é que a sua lista é o `arrayemp1` e o seu `addEmprestimo` deveria estar operando sobre essa lista.

```
if(emprestimo.equals(emp1))
```

Isso nunca vai dar certo, pois `emp1` é do tipo `Emprestimo` e `emprestimo` é do tipo `ArrayList<Emprestimo>`. Objetos de tipos diferentes nunca serão iguais em qualquer implementação sadia do método `equals`.

Sugiro que coloque a lista em uma classe só para ela, fora de `Emprestimo`. Use [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), pois `Set`s não permitem duplicatas. E aproveite que [o método `add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) retorna um `boolean` dizendo se deu certo ou não (se não der certo é duplicata):

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class ListaEmprestimos {

    private Collection<Emprestimo> emprestimos = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public ListaEmprestimos() {
    }

    public void addEmprestimo(Emprestimo emp1) {
        if (emprestimos.add(emp1)) {
             System.out.println("Não é possível realizar mais que um empréstimo.");
        } else {
             System.out.println("Empréstimo realizado com sucesso.");
        }
    }

    public void imprimirEmprestimos() {
        for (Elemento e : emprestimos) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Tendo isso, o seu `main` fica assim:

```
public class ControlaRevista {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListaEmprestimos lista = new ListaEmprestimos();

        System.out.println("\n== EMPRESTIMO ==");
        lista.addEmpretimo(new Emprestimo("SUPER HOMEM", "2/2/2020", "2/2/2020", "Alex", "Gaspar"));
        lista.addEmpretimo(new Emprestimo("SUPER HOMEM", "2/2/2020", "2/2/2020", "Alex", "Gaspar"));

        lista.imprimirEmprestimos();
    }
}
```

Por fim, é importante implementar os métodos `equals` e `hashCode` corretamente na sua classe `Emprestimo`:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public final class Emprestimo {
    private final String nome;
    private final String dataEmprestimo;
    private final String dataDevolucao;
    private final String nomeAmigo;
    private final String nomeLocal;

    public Emprestimo(String nome, String dataEmprestimo, String dataDevolucao, String nomeAmigo, String nomeLocal) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.dataEmprestimo = dataEmprestimo;
        this.dataDevolucao = dataDevolucao;
        this.nomeAmigo = nomeAmigo;
        this.nomeLocal = nomeLocal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Emprestimo)) return false;
        Emprestimo outro = (Emprestimo) obj;
        return Objects.equals(nome, outro.nome)
                && Objects.equals(dataEmprestimo, outro.dataEmprestimo)
                && Objects.equals(dataDevolucao, outro.dataDevolucao)
                && Objects.equals(nomeAmigo, outro.nomeAmigo)
                && Objects.equals(nomeLocal, outro.nomeLocal);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(nome, dataEmprestimo, dataDevolucao, nomeAmigo, nomeLocal);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexJ Se esta resposta resolveu seu problema e não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida, clique no "✔️" que está à esquerda da resposta para marcá-la como aceita/correta, o que também marca a sua pergunta como solucionada/respondida. Caso contrário, sinta-se livre para comentar.

Comment: Oi Victor, obrigado pelo retorno. Eu realizei o ajuste, porém, no resultado após compilar ainda exibe duas vezes a mensagem "Não é possível realizar mais que -----> um empréstimo." sendo que está repetindo somente uma vez no addEmprestimo, não sei onde estou errando. Eu atualizei o post com as classe de como estão no meu código. Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.